# Unable to alert the data after jQuery ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to send data using ajax and getting response

This is my ajax code

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery( "#district" ).change(function() {
        var lvType = jQuery(this).val();

        if(lvType == '')
        {
            alert('Please Enter District First');
            return false;
        }
jQuery.ajax({
        url: '../wp-content/plugins/sevaapkedwar/menu-pages/search.php?q='+lvType,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'text/html',
        success:function(data)
        {
        alert('ajax call finished successfully');
        },
        error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } 
     });
});});
```

and my `search.php` code is

```
global $wpdb;
$q = $_GET['q'];
$get_m = "select * from `sevaapkedwar_area` where `district_name` = '$q'";
$get_st_l = $wpdb->get_results($get_m);
//print_r($get_st_l);
$json = array();
    foreach($get_st_l as $get_st_l){
      $json[] = array(
        'id' => $get_st_l->id, 
       'area' => $get_st_l->area_name 
      );
    }
    echo json_encode($json);
```

When I am running this code then in console the status of query is `200 OK with data [{"id":"8","area":"City1"}]`

But I am unable to alert the message `ajax call finished successfully`

What I am missing

Comment: why type: `text/html` and not `application/json` when you are expecting json?

Comment: I have tried with application/json also but no response

Comment: malformed json can be the reason

Answer (score 0):

in ajax code, change dataType to json. dataType: The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. some of the possible values are - xml, json, script, or HTML. Reference: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
dataType: 'json',
```

In the PHP code add header before the last echo statement.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);
```

Reference: [Returning JSON from a PHP Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script/4064468#4064468)

Now your code should work in the correct way.
You can check/clone my working git [repo](https://github.com/pavanyogi/return-json-response-to-ajax-call-php) for the ajax demo.